# Change MySql Database in Model, Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have model Stat:

```
class Stat < ActiveRecord::Base

  establish_connection(
    :adapter  => "mysql2",
    :database => @db
  )

end
```

I want change database name, using params[:id]

Example, if url

```
/stat/?id=db01
```

model Stat:

```
@db = "db01"
```

Comment: I assume you'll have to hook into the controller action that receives the /stat request and have it 'reset' an instance of the Stat class to use the desired db.

Comment: @railsdog, how to do it? I tried - did not work (